# Conncection refused error in hadoop-2.6.0 while running word count program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I would like to know the root cause of this error. When I started running the conventional word count program in hadoop-2.6.0 the following exception is generated. your suggestions will be much appreciated.

```
  16/03/16 11:21:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    16/03/16 11:21:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1458107299826_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1458107299826_0002 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1458107299826_0002_000002. Got exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From abc-OptiPlex-3020/127.0.1.1 to abc-OptiPlex-3020:52890 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

my /etc/hosts file is as follows: from master system

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   abc-OptiPlex-3020

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.12.106  HadoopMaster
192.168.12.105  HadoopSlave1
```

Comment: The same error is getting after a long try ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Install openssh server and client
2. ssh username@hostname